# Passing FileList on dropping files, from a child component to the parent

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to pass the fileList from a child component when dropping files in a specific area. I can process the files using the input file dialog box.

```
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { storage, db } from '../../firebase';
import { ref, getDownloadURL, uploadBytesResumable } from "firebase/storage";
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

const FileDrop = ({name}) => {

    const [isDragActive, setisDragActive] = useState(false);
    const acceptedFiles = [1,2,3]
    const fileDragValues = useRef({});

    function handleFile(list) {
        console.log(list.current); 
      }
      
    // handle drag events
    const handleDrag = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        if (e.type === "dragenter" || e.type === "dragover") {
            setisDragActive(true);
        } else if (e.type === "dragleave") {
            setisDragActive(false);
        } 
    };
    
    // triggers when file is dropped
    const handleDrop = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        setisDragActive(false);
        fileDragValues.current = e.dataTransfer.files; 
        if (e.dataTransfer.files && e.dataTransfer.files[0]) {
            handleFile(fileDragValues);
        }
    };
    
    // triggers when file is selected with click
    const handleChange = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.target.files && e.target.files[0]) {
            handleFile(e.target.files);
        }
    };
    
      
    return (
        <>
                <div className="flex items-center justify-center w-full" 
                    onDragOver={handleDrag} onDragLeave={handleDrag} onDrop={handleDrop} >
                    <label htmlFor="dropzone-file" 
                        className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full border-2 border-dashed rounded-lg cursor-pointer" >
                        <div 
                            className={`flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-full py-2 
                                ${isDragActive ? "border-stone-300 bg-stone-200" : "bg-gray-100" }`} >
                            <svg className="w-8 h-8 mb-4 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 20 16">
                                <path stroke="currentColor" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="M13 13h3a3 3 0 0 0 0-6h-.025A5.56 5.56 0 0 0 16 6.5 5.5 5.5 0 0 0 5.207 5.021C5.137 5.017 5.071 5 5 5a4 4 0 0 0 0 8h2.167M10 15V6m0 0L8 8m2-2 2 2"/>
                            </svg>
                            
                                <div>
                                    <p className="mb-2 text-center text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">{ isDragActive ? "Drop files now..." : <><span className='font-semibold'>Click to upload</span> or drag and drop</> }</p>
                                    <p className="text-xs text-center text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">Ready to upload {acceptedFiles.length} {acceptedFiles.length > 1 ? 'files' : 'file' }</p> 
                                </div>
                            <p></p>
                        </div>
                        <input className="hidden" type="file" id="dropzone-file" name={name} multiple onChange={handleChange}  />
                    </label>
                </div> 
        </>
    );
}


export default function Modal({close}) {

    const [progressPercent, setProgressPercent] = useState(0);
    const fileDragValues = useRef({});

    const handleSubmits = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(e.target.files.files)
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        
        const files = e.target.files.files[0];        
        // handleSubmits(files)

        if (!files) return null;
        const storageRef = ref(storage, `files/${files.name}`);
        const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, files);

        uploadTask.on("state_changed",
            (snapshot) => {
                const progress = Math.round((snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100)
                setProgressPercent(progress)
            },
            (error) => {   
                switch (error.code) {
                  case 'cancelled':
                    alert('Upload has been cancelled')
                    break;
                  default :  
                    break;
                }
              },
            () => {
                e.target[0].value = ''
                getDownloadURL(storageRef).then((downloadURL) => {
                    setDoc(doc(db, "albums", files.name), {
                        name: files.name, 
                        size: files.size,
                        modified: files.lastModifiedDate,
                        type: files.type,
                        url: downloadURL
                      });  
                })
            }
        )
      }

    return (
        <>
            <div 
                className="justify-center items-center flex overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto fixed inset-0 z-50 outline-none focus:outline-none"
                onClick={() => { close() }}>
                <div className="relative w-auto my-6 mx-auto max-w-6xl" id="content" onClick={e => { e.stopPropagation() }}>
                {/*content*/}
                <div className="border-0 rounded-lg shadow-lg relative flex flex-col w-full bg-white outline-none focus:outline-none">
                    {/*header*/}
                    <div className="flex items-start justify-between p-5 border-b border-solid border-slate-200 rounded-t">
                    <h3 className="text-3xl font-semibold">
                        Upload Album
                    </h3>
                    <button
                        className="p-1 ml-auto bg-transparent border-0 float-right text-3xl leading-none font-semibold"
                        onClick={close}
                    >
                        <span className="bg-transparent h-6 w-6 text-2xl block  hover:text-red-500">
                        ×
                        </span>
                    </button>
                    </div>
                    {/*body*/}
                    <form className='app__form' name='upload_file' id="file_upload" onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmits(e)}>
                        <div className="relative p-6 flex-auto w-[700px]">
                            <div className="mb-3">
                                <input
                                className="w-full rounded-lg border-2 border-gray-200 p-3 placeholder-zinc-500"
                                placeholder="Album Name"
                                type="text"
                                name="album"
                                />
                            </div>

                            <div className="mb-3">
                                <select name="collection" id="collection" className="w-full rounded-lg border-2 border-gray-200 p-3 placeholder-zinc-500">
                                    <option value="new">New Collection</option>
                                    <option value="moderated">Moderated</option>
                                    <option value="unmoderated">Unmoderated</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div className="mb-3">
                                <input
                                className="w-full rounded-lg border-2 border-gray-200 p-3 placeholder-zinc-500"
                                placeholder="Prefix"
                                type="text"
                                name="prefix"
                                />
                            </div>

                            <div className="mb-3 rounded-lg">
                                <FileDrop name="files" />
                                
                                <progress className="w-full mt-3" value={progressPercent} max="100" />
                            </div>
                           
                        </div>

                        {/*footer*/}
                        <div className="flex items-center justify-end p-6 border-t border-solid border-slate-200 rounded-b">
                        <button
                            className="text-white background-transparent font-bold uppercase px-6 py-3 text-sm rounded bg-red-500
                            hover:bg-red-600  mr-1 mb-1" type="button" onClick={close}>
                            Cancel
                        </button>
                        <button
                            className="bg-emerald-500 text-white hover:bg-emerald-600 font-bold uppercase text-sm px-6 py-3 
                            rounded outline-none focus:outline-none mr-1 mb-1 ease-linear transition-all duration-150"
                            type="submit">
                            Upload
                        </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="opacity-40 fixed inset-0 z-40 bg-stone-500"></div>
        </>
    ) ;
}
```

I've tried an example with text and it works, however, when I try to pass an object React throws an error.

What technique should I use to pass the object around?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `useRef` and `useEffect` hooks to pass the `fileList` from the child component to the parent.

In the child component, you can create a `useRef` variable to store the `fileList` and also add a `useEffect` hook to update the `fileList` whenever it changes

Comment: Thanks Afzal. It's a good indication but not the answer I was looking for. The way I solved this is by adding a function as a prop in the Child component.

onDragOver={handleDrag} onDragLeave={handleDrag} onDrop={(e) => { handleDrop(e); drop(e)}}>